# How to get C-` key combo recognized in Emacs under Mac?

Tags: macos, emacs, terminal, iterm

I use console Emacs in iTerm and Terminal.app. A package needs the key combo C-backtick which I can't get Emacs to receive through either of the terminal emulators. It's easy to confirm by using C-h k, and then typing C-backtick. It gives the result for the ` key instead.

Is there any way to get iTerm or Terminal.app to send this key combo properly?

Comment: Similar question on [emacs.se]: [http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/13950/c-s-n-and-c-not-working-in-emacs-if-running-within-terminal](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/13950/c-s-n-and-c-not-working-in-emacs-if-running-within-terminal)

Answer (score 0):

The answer really depends on what you are expecting:

- If you are looking for some behavior *not* in a terminal emulator, Emacs could detect the <kbd>control</kbd> modifier independently of the actual character.
- *In* a terminal emulator, the usual effect of the <kbd>control</kbd> modifier is to logically-AND the value of the character with 0x1f (31).  The <kbd>`</kbd> character's value is 0x60 (96), so the usual result would be 0 (ASCII NUL).  You can do this in Terminal.app with a <kbd>control</kbd> modifying the <kbd>space</kbd> character.

Just to complicate things a little, xterm can be told to send an escape sequence such as

```
ESC [ 2 7 ; 5 ; 9 6 ~
```

for <kbd>control</kbd> <kbd>`</kbd>, however that's not implemented by other terminal emulators.  (This is the *[modifyOtherKeys](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html)* feature mentioned in the manual).

Comment: Thanks. iTerm allows me to send arbitrary escape sequences, but when I tried the sequence you mentioned, it did not work. Can you confirm the sequence is correct?

Comment: The sequence shown was *sent* by xterm when `modifyOtherKeys` was set (by a control sequence).  Neither Terminal nor iTerm2 recognizes the sequence.